# Vinagre only gives 800x600 RDC resolution, how to increase?

Tags: 11.10, display, resolution, vinagre

Using Vinagre on Ubuntu 11.10, when I RDC into a remote Windows XP machine, I only get a 800x600 resolution on the remote display. I can't increase it on the Windows machine, it's stuck at 800x600. Any way to customise?

If I use Terminal Server Client on Ubuntu instead of Vinagre, I can adjust the res. Any way to fix for Vinagre?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out either.  I'm now using remmina based on this post: http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=3411

remmina has more (or easier to find) settings, right when you set up the connection.

-Amir

Comment: Thanks, I have gone with remmina and it is way better! The current vinagre even removes the bookmarks sidebar and disallows editing.

Comment: I filed a bug for this on launchpad here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vinagre/+bug/890396

Answer (score 2):

A quick hack:

1. mv /usr/bin/rdesktop /usr/bin/rdesktop.bin
2. create the file /usr/bin/rdesktop to with the contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   /usr/bin/rdesktop.bin -g 1024x768 $*
   ```
3. chmod 755 /usr/bin/rdesktop

The remote desktop viewer, vinagre, just runs rdesktop, so this in effect sets the default geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Remmina → Vinagre, if only because it allows different RDP resolutions, and it includes a feature to import `tsclient` config files.

Comment: Is your suggestion to use Remmina instead of Vinagre? Please specify.